# Pocket Legends, Can't find suitable quests for newbie

Tags: pocket-legends

I am a new player in [Pocket Legends MMO(iPhone game)](http://www.pocketlegends.com/) world.

At the beginning I am a character of level 2. Now I want to explore different places. But wherever I go, it says you can't enter until you are of X level, where X is very high.

So, I have 2 options to increase my level(I guess)
1. Kill someone
2. Complete objectives.

But, I don't find places where a newbie can kill enemies. I found someplace where there are lots of skeletons, but I can't kill them alone. I need a party. So, 1st option out of reach.

Second option is completing different quests. But, here there are also level issues. Most of the objectives I take require a high level character. I don't find quests that ares suitable for level 2-3 character.

What do I do in this situation to level up my character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I did to level up both my Mage and Warrior type characters was walk into the shining portal in the town after collecting a bunch of quests.  It drops you into a zone that at least I could handle, and random people join the group as you play (or you join an active group on that map).

Answer (score 1):

Go to world map and then tap the forest haven then join game. Choose the game with most players to level up quickly. Dont forget to use the daily elixir found at vincent the vendor. It boost all your stats x3 including your exp.